# Javascript array in VSCode is being split between multiple lines

Tags: javascript, arrays, visual-studio-code, format

I am working with arrays in VSCode, when it saves on format the array is split up to one item per line[screenshot of array formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ox2P.png).
All my arrays equal over 12000 lines, i might be missing something but cannot find any options in VSCode.
Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.
Many Thanks

I  tried to create a very long array and on saving the array was split up into thousands of lines with one item per line, i expected the array to stay multiple items a line but instead the formatter split it up into one item per line.

Comment: Read this https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/352

Comment: Can it be collapsed using code folding?

Comment: Thanks folks. code folding seems to be the short term answer until i work out eslint.